# rtweet - Warning: 32 - Could not authenticate you

Tags: r, twitter, twitter-oauth, rtweet

I notice a few people have encountered issues with rtweet authorization. I followed this vignette which assumes people are familiar with authentication protocols. Newbies such as myself, struggle with this.

```
vignette("auth", package = "rtweet")`
```

I stored all keys and tokens in my `.Renviron` file.  This is the code I use to access keys and tokens:

```
require(rtweet)
require(httpuv)

api_key <- Sys.getenv("TWITTER")
api_secret_key <- Sys.getenv("TWITTER_SECRET")
access_token <- Sys.getenv("ACCESS_TOKEN")
access_token_secret <- Sys.getenv("ACCESS_SECRET")
```

I then create a token using this code:

```
token <- create_token(
  app = "my_app",
  consumer_key = api_key,
  consumer_secret = api_secret_key,
  access_token = access_token,
  access_secret = access_token_secret)
```

Next, I check if a token has been created:

```
get_token()
```

I get this response:

```
<Token>
<oauth_endpoint>
 request:   https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token
 authorize: https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate
 access:    https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token
<oauth_app> my_app
  key:    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  secret: <hidden>
<credentials> oauth_token, oauth_token_secret
---
```

I restarted R and run a query as follows:

```
tweet_data <- search_tweets("#plasticrecycling", 
                 n = 2000, 
                 include_rts = F, 
                 lang = "en")
```

And end up with this error:

```
Warning: 32 - Could not authenticate you.
Warning message:
Could not authenticate you.
```

Can someone please explain why this is happening?  A similar issue was reported here `https://github.com/ropensci/rtweet/issues/439` but it was closed without a clear answer. I am not sure if `create_token()` is a once-off thing or must be initiated each time I use R. I notice this added to my `.Renviron` file:

```
TWITTER_PAT=/Users/bob/.rtweet_token.rds
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you crossposted this on https://discuss.ropensci.org/t/rtweet-authorization/2938. I have answered there.

Answer (score 1):

Loading the latest development version of `rtweet` solves the problem I was encountering:

```
remotes::install_github("rOpenSci/rtweet")

packageVersion("rtweet")
[1] ‘0.7.0.9026’
```

This version makes it easier to authenticate things.

```
auth <- rtweet_app(bearer_token = Sys.getenv("BEARER_TOKEN"))

auth_save(auth, "my_app")

auth_list()
[1] "my_app"

auth_as(auth = "my_app")

tweets <- search_tweets("#plasticrecycling",
                        include_rts = F,
                        n = 1000,
                        lang = "en")
```

One only has to run the `rtweet_app()` once and then save the output. Every time one restarts R and loads a Twitter script, one simply has to execute `auth_as(auth = "your_app")`

I was confused by `OAuth1.0` versus `OAuth2.0` on the Twitter API page. It also did not help reading the wrong online manual pages for a different version of `rtweet`!

Kudos to [llrs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2886003/llrs) for helping me resolve my issue.